# Laravel Routes vs Mod-rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, laravel, laravel-3

So - I'm new to Laravel and we're using version 3.

I have a home page setup & working - say http://dev.mywebsite.com

Now I want to click a link on the page and redirect to a nice SEO friendly URL, but pass in the variables. In straight PHP this is simple - I can make http://dev.mywebsite.com/vacancies/town/page2 rewrite as http://dev.mywebsite.com/?where=town&page=2

But I can't get this to work in Laravel.

I know the full answer is to create controllers & views, but I have all the logic for the display in an included file so don't really want to change... is there any way to do this using either routes or mod-rewrite?

Thanks

Comment: If I understand, you want to match the route `http://dev.mywebsite.com/?where=town&page=2` to your existing file?

Comment: Did you tried to add that route within your `routes.php` file and include you file?

Comment: That's the problem - I'm not sure how...

Comment: Ok, got it. So the pattern you want to match should look as: `/?where={var1}&page={var2}`, right? Any constraint in those values?

Comment: Var1 is text, Var2 is numeric - that's all...

Comment: I'm not sure if possible to route by query string, I will check it out... may I ask a another question? Why do you prefer to use query string instead of route pattern?

Comment: Simply because I don't yet fully understand routes and am trying to get this fixed quickly without rewriting the CMS we're using... thanks for your help!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35772/discussion-between-rubens-mariuzzo-and-jezb)

Answer (score 0):

Although I strongly recommend you to make a view with that file, you can still use [PHP's Output Control](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) to avoid messing with Laravel's rendering flow:

```
Route::get('your-nice-url-here', function() {
    ob_start();
    include 'your-raw-php-here';
    return Response::make(ob_get_clean());
});
```